# How can I make an extended search in wordpress like %some%

Tags: wordpress, search

i need to make a serch in my post titles for a part of the word,
something like this

```
$args = array ( 'category_name' => '%som%');
query_posts( $args );
```

So I get by this 'something' and also 'besomer'

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like wordpress already does this by default. However, you could filter `posts_where` to change the default search functionality. That would look something like this:

```
<?php
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_search_where');

function my_search_where($where) {
    if (is_search()) {
        // change the where string with a preg_replace()
    }
    return $where;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to `like_escape( '%string%' );`.

Comment: That's not necessary since wordpress already escapes it before this filter is applied.

Comment: Could you tell me where (file + line-nr.)? Because that's not about a _title_ or I missunderstood something.

Comment: You would want to put that in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: I know that. Just realized now that the search would be _by title_.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It works! [by the way, it's not on the default of WP]